# when to use locks for MYSQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, data-consistency

I am wondering if it is necessary for data consistency concerns to use locks for none-persistent connections to MYSQL server. While performing changes to tables accessed by multiple users at the same time. To illustrate more I will use a scenario that I am working with.

Lets's assume I am using PDO and manual transactions with `beginTransaction()` and `commit()`
, and I am doing a simple `INSERT INTO TABLE` query. The table has a Primary key and it is auto-incremented. I am interested to reuse The ID column of the inserted row  after insertion, with help of `lastInsertId();` To create another Insert withing the same transaction and use the ID as a value in  another table

Do I have to use table locks to prevent data inconstancy? If so what is a good practice of doing that?

Comment: convert your database engine into InnoDB

Comment: it is already in  InnoDB